# In what way does the zero vector need to exist for a subspace to be linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck on a homework question that asks if **W** is a linear subspace of **V** where **V** are all polynomials with real coefficients $P(\mathbb{R})$ and $W:\{\text{span}(X, X^2+X+1, X^3+X^2+2X,X^3-1)\}$.

Here is what I doubt. There is no $X$ such that $w=0$, so $0$ is not in $W$? Or is it, because we can scale $w$ with $0$: $0w=0$. But, won't zero always be in a subspace then?

Comment: Do you mean $W:\ldots$ instead of $V:\ldots$, where you define the subset? It is a span so yes, it is a linear subspace. The zero vector is in there because the span consists of **all** linear combinations: take all coefficients $0$.

Comment: (1) For any vector space $\Bbb V$ and subset $S \subseteq \Bbb V$, $\operatorname{span}(S)$ is a subspace. (2) Any vector subspace is itself a vector space (with respect to the restrictions of the operations on the original space) and in particular contains the zero element.

Comment: @StackTD, yes that's what I meant. Edited!

Comment: In the second sentence you say, "There is no $X$ such $w=0$, so $0$ is not in $W$?"  What is $w$?  There was no previous mention of it, although in an earlier edit you had (I think) mentioned coefficients $w_1,w_2,w_3$.  The current form of the Question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero vector is always an element of the span. It is equal to the linear combination of 'generating' vectors each multiplied by the real number zero, for example. So if $V=sp\{u,v\}$, then ${\bf 0}=0u+0v$. Hence ${\bf 0}\in V$.